"Switch input sources individually for each window" does not work for Wine applications
This was a problem present in the past several releases of Ubuntu. Currently I am using Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop and the problem is still not solved.
I have three keyboard layouts for my current Linux user and I prefer each application window to use its own layout. So, I have selected Switch input sources individually for each window in the Keyboard → Input Source Switching setting.
This works well on most windows, but there are some exceptions, the most notable being any wine application window. When I try to switch the keyboard layout for a wine application window (either through mouse by clicking the relevant keyboard layout in the panel or by using the keyboard combination as defined for the Switch to next input source keyboard shortcut) the layout indicator seems to be switching to the new layout momentarily, but then reverts to the old one immediately.
The only solution for switching to another keyboard layout in a wine application is to Use the same source for all windows setting which is something I do not prefer.
What solutions or workarounds can be suggested?
